# What are the heuristic detection techniques most often used in modern AVs?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware, detection

Whenever I read books or academic papers and the subject of heuristic malware detection is brought up they always say the same thing: "it can be either static or dynamic", "it may use emulation", "may detect new malware, but higher chance of false-positives", and that's about the extent of how I've seen it described. What, specifically, are the techniques modern AVs use for heuristic detection?

Comment: I think this question is way too broad. AV can use hundreds of different heuristics that differ between vendors.

Comment: @forest I don't think I am looking for that level of granularity. I imagine that whatever techniques exist could be divided into maybe a handful of categories or that there are a few that are used so often that they can be mentioned specifically. At the very least, there must be a way to answer the question more specifically than saying "it can be either static or dynamic".

Comment: Your question asks "What, specifically, are the techniques modern AVs use for heuristic detection?" That's different from "what categories of heuristics are there?" Also, do you know what a heuristic algorithm is and how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Malwarebytes:

> ...if an application is programmed to remove important system files, the anti-malware software may flag it as malware (since applications should not be doing that). But, heuristic analysis can sometimes result in “false positives,” or programs flagged as malware that are actually legitimate.
>   https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/how-does-anti-malware-work/

*Most* modern heuristic detection is a flag-and-score system. Basically each program scanned will get a score based on how shady it is, these scores are obtained by counting the amount of 'flags' a program gets. Flags are activities monitored and reported by the anti-virus when it attaches itself to a process. These are usually renegade activities such as modifying or deleting system files in the background, escalating privileges without user input, or downloading data from a remote server without displaying UI. After a scan is complete, these flag scores can be averaged to find how far away from normal some program's activity could be. After a certain threshold in the bell-curve, it is considered too mysterious to be normal and detected as a virus or PUP.

There are different approach between products, all with trade-offs, but all end in the same result:

- System emulation, flag shady activity. (some malware can detect virtualization)
- Scan binary, flag byte-marks associated with shady activity. (can give off false positives to similar less-shady logic)
- Attach to running agent, flag shady activity in real-time. (debug-traps can halt detection)
- Decomiple/reverse-engineer, flag shady code. (Code obfuscators can throw off results)